# How to pack this project by Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake, archive

I am trying to pack this project by Xcode: [https://github.com/0xtaruhi/FDPinHelper](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), which can be built by Xcode successfully.
The goal now is copying Frameworks and static library it needs into its directory, making it portable to run. However, now it is dependent on my local environment.

```
cd FDPinHelper
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DQT_ROOT_DIR=/your/path/to/Qt -G"Xcode" ..
cmake --build .
```

(`/your/path/to/Qt` should be `/Applications`)

### What I have tried

First, I tried to **Add Copy Files Building Phase** to copy the required Frameworks and static libraries into the Resources folder.
[image: 6 Needed Frameworks And Static Library]
Then, I added these to **Link Binary With Libraries** Phase. However, there was an error in the link Phase: "Library not found for -lflatui". Delete "libflatui.a" could solve this problem.(I don't know the reason)
[image: Error Message]
It could be archived at that moment but still not capable of running on a mac without QT.

I imitated another project's method and changed the **Runpath Search Paths**, which seems uneffective either.
[image: Another Project Screenshot]
I believe some linking-related settings should be modified like **Other Linker Flags**, or something should be added to CMakeLists.txt.

This is the first software Project I participate in. Besides, I am not very familiar with Cmake and Xcode, which makes this problem possibly seem silly. Therefore, I am terribly grateful for every of your patient response!

[Xcode Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZrn0.png)
The architecture is x86.

### Further Explanation

The desired directory should be like: [image: Directory] It contains all needed Frameworks and dynamic/static libraries.

Now my app can run on my PC, but errors will occur when I attempt to run on other PCs.
[image]

Comment: I don't understand the problem, but see some keywords, and maybe the following will be useful to you: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/BundleUtilities.html

Comment: "making it portable to run" - The executables/libraries in the CMake **build** tree are never "portable". You need to **install** the project (installation is described by different flavors of [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) command. Concerning RPATH, see https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling. If you want to get more concrete help, then you need to provide more details in the question post. At least, the **code** and **error message**. See [ask].

Comment: I have updated the description and error messags. Your advice is all very helpful and I will study it thoroughly.